# Scrape href not working with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I have copies of this very code that I am trying to do and every time I copy it line by line it isn't working right. I am more than frustrated and can't seem to figure out where it is not working. What I am trying to do is go to a website, scrap the different ratings pages which are labelled A, B, C ... etc. Then I am going to each site to pull the total number of pages they are using. I am trying to scrape the `<span class='letter-pages' href='/ratings/A/1'` and so on. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
hrefs = []
ratings = []
ks = []
pages_scrape = []

for href in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'href' in href.attrs:
        hrefs.append(href.attrs['href'])
for good_ratings in hrefs:
    if good_ratings.startswith('/ratings/'):
        ratings.append(url[:-9]+good_ratings)
# elif good_ratings.startswith('/401k'):
#     ks.append(url[:-9]+good_ratings)
del ratings[0]
del ratings[27:]
print(ratings)

for each_rating in ratings:
    page  = requests.get(each_rating)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for href in soup.find('span', class_='letter-pages'):
        #Not working Here
        pages_scrape.append(href.attrs['href'])
        # Will print all the anchor tags with hrefs if I remove the above comment.
        print(href)
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Are you getting error messages? Is nothing printing out?

Comment: Not working means I am getting error messages. `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'attrs'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the href prematurely. You are trying to extract the attribute directly from a `span` tag that has nested `a` tags, rather than a list of `a` tags.

```
for each_rating in ratings:
    page  = requests.get(each_rating)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='letter-pages')
    for a in span.find_all('a'):
        href = a.get('href')
        pages_scrape.append(href)
```

I didn't test this on all pages, but it worked for the first one. You pointed out that on some of the pages the content wasn't getting scraped, which is due to the `span` search returning `None`. To get around this you can do something like:

```
for each_rating in ratings:
    page  = requests.get(each_rating)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='letter-pages')
    if span:
        for a in span.find_all('a'):
            href = a.get('href')
            pages_scrape.append(href)
            print(href)
    else:
        print('span.letter-pages not found on ' + page)
```

Depending on your use case you might want to do something different, but this will indicate to you which pages don't match your scraping model and need to be manually investigated.

Comment: It worked but I kept getting an traceback error because I was finding that some of the pages didn't have anything to scrape. How could I fix that?

Comment: You can check if the `span` element was found or not with an if/else. I'll update my post to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do `find_all` instead of `find` -- so change

```
for href in soup.find('span', class_='letter-pages'):
```

to

```
for href in soup.find_all('span', class_='letter-pages'):
```

You want to be iterating over a *list of* tags, not a single tag. `find` would give you a single tag object. When you iterate over a single tag, you iterate get `NavigableString` objects. `find_all` gives you the list of tag objects you want.